# How to sum float values by truncating the decimal places of each record using awk?

Tags: unix, awk, precision

In the below example, when I do awk sum, it gives the sum using 3 decimal places.

```
A|1.668
B|1.668
C|1.668
D|1.668
E|1.668
F|1.668
G|1.668
H|1.668
```

Script used:
`nawk -v x=2 -F '|' '{rows++; sum+=$x} END { printf ("%s|%0.2f\n", rows, sum) }' testfile.dat`

Output of above script is 13.34 (which is truncated value of 13.344)
Output needed is 13.28 (i.e., sum of 8 times 1.66 instead of 1.668)

How can I sum by truncating the decimal places?

Edit: 
I tried with the actual value for few records as given in the sample. The file contains value in 2 decimal places to 10 decimal places also.

```
537.45
129.36
241.93
143.58
279.65
348.37
239.27
6561.52
6682.61
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your sample input, output, and code to be legible and usable on this forum. I fixed your input for you as a starting point/example.

Comment: If your real input file `contains value in 2 decimal places to 10 decimal places also` then include such values in your sample input/output.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk -v x=2 -F'|' '{sub(/.$/,"",$2); sum+=$2} END{printf "%d|%0.2f\n", NR, sum}' file
8|13.28
```

or maybe this using GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk -v x=2 -F'|' '{sum+=gensub(/(\...).*$/,"\\1",1,$2)} END{printf "%d|%0.2f\n", NR, sum}' file
8|13.28
```

If not then edit your question to better explain your requirements and add some more truly representative sample input/output that the above approach does not work for.

Given your comments, you may need to just do string manipulation around the math to avoid any floating point math issues:

```
$ awk -v x=2 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {sum+=gensub(/\.(..).*/,"\\1",1,$x)} END{print NR, gensub(/..$/,".&",1,sum)}' file
8|13.28
```

Comment: Your approach works with small data set.
The sum is not working because the awk/sum converts 2 decimal value to 8 decimal value before applying the sum.

ValueInFile -> ValuePrintedUsingAWK
1392992.38 -> 1392992.3799999999
1653444.68 -> 1653444.6799999999

If I add the value in the file it will match. But for some reason awk sum doesnt take the precision in the file instead does the sume at 8 precision digits.
Hence there is a difference in the sum.
Is there a way to correct this in awk?

Since millions of records are processed by this command, it gives a significant difference.

Comment: As I mentioned, if the above doesn't work then `edit your question to better explain your requirements and add some more truly representative sample input/output that the above approach does not work for.`. Is the list of numbers under `Edit` in your question some new sample input? If so add the expected output for that input to your question so we have something to test a potential solution with and please format it all properly, see my first comment under your question.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
awk  -F '|' '{sum += int(100 * $2) / 100} END {print sum}'
```

Comment: Welcome to computer floating point math: `awk 'BEGIN {n=279.65; printf "%.14f\t%.14f\n", n, int(n * 100)}'`

Comment: Your approach works with small data set.
The sum is not working because the awk/sum converts 2 decimal value to 8 decimal value before applying the sum.

ValueInFile -> ValuePrintedUsingAWK
1392992.38 -> 1392992.3799999999
1653444.68 -> 1653444.6799999999

If I add the value in the file it will match. But for some reason awk sum doesnt take the precision in the file instead does the sume at 8 precision digits.
Hence there is a difference in the sum.
Is there a way to correct this in awk?

Since millions of records are processed by this command, it gives a significant difference.

Comment: This is the implementation of floating point numbers used by many (most?) languages. Some numbers simply cannot be exactly represented in that format. I advise you to use string manipulation to do the truncation, use string manipulation to remove the decimal point so you're summing integers, then add the decimal point back in.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`:

```
awk -F '[|.]' '{sum+=sprintf("%s.%.2s",$2, $3)} END {print sum}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution in perl using floating point numbers with precision 2 digits after decimal. This will give correct result even if the total sum has more significant figures than what normal floating point values can hold. There are ways to make it faster using other math library, see https://metacpan.org/pod/bignum#Math-Library.

```
perl -Mbignum=p,-2 -F'\|' -lnE '
    BEGIN {
        Math::BigFloat->round_mode("trunc");
    }
    $s += Math::BigFloat->new($F[1]);
    END { say $s }' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `bc` for exact calculation, and GNU `sed` for string manipulation:

```
sed -E 's/.*\|([0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}).*/\1/; H; $!d; g; s/.//; y/\n/+/' in.txt | bc
```

assuming that there are at least two digits after the decimal point.